# How to use ffmpegwrapper for python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

So i have this simple code using [ffmpegwrapper](http://vbffmpegwrapper.codeplex.com/), and it doesnt seem to do anything...
so whats the prob? thanks

```
from ffmpegwrapper import FFmpeg, Input, Output, VideoCodec, VideoFilter

input_video = Input('bob.mp4')
output_video = Output('bob2.webm')
FFmpeg('ffmpeg', input_video, output_video)
```

(this is the full code btw)

Ill take other alternatives... just not the `subprocess` command

Comment: Can you show the actual `ffmpeg` command line and the resulting complete console output (unless the issue precedes ffmpeg execution)? I'm guessing it's using the `ffmpeg` tool and not the API. Also, your link states, "No longer being developed due to no funding or ad support".

Comment: Yea now i'm started to think that because it isn't being developed it must be broken. You now of any ffmpeg wrappers for python?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add .run() at the end of FFmpeg('ffmpeg', input_video, output_video) to have it actually start executing the binary.